# Unable to parse JSON in swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I am having issue to grab value from JSON in swift 4.

```
{
    "meta": {"expiration": 0,"flags": 33456},
    "json": "{\"key\":\"string\",\"value\":{\"failed_attempts\":\"1\"}}",
    "xattrs": {}
}
```

The code I have tried

```
if let resultData = responseBody["json"] as? [String: AnyObject]{

   if let val = resultData["value"] as? [String: AnyObject]{

      if let attempt = val["failed_attempt"] as? String {
         print(attempt)

         }
    }
}
```

I have tried to print below line, it correctly prints all object inside json array but when ever i tried to add a return type as [String: AnyObject] it returns nil value. Could someone please give me some advise.

> response["json"]

Comment: what's resultData ?

Comment: You should use Codable for Swift 4

Comment: @AliAbbas I have edited the code to reflect _resultData_.

Comment: the [] brackets suggest that your JSON at the top level is an array

Comment: Just ran query again from postman, and its a curly bracket actually.

Comment: can you try to put some key/value inside meta and xattrs ?

Comment: @AliAbbas added key/value inside _meta_ but _xattrs_ is empty so doesn't have any value/s.

Comment: The value for key `json` is a (JSON) string which must be deserialized separately.

Comment: Note that the JSON uses the key failed_attempts whereas the code uses failed_attempt!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `AnyObject` with `Any`. Dictionaries are structs, not objects, so that cast will fail.

I would also suggest learning about Codable to handle JSON in the future.

Edit:

You'll need to serialize your data into a JSON object first. The `Data` class is not automatically converted to JSON.

```
do {
    let jsonRoot = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseBody, options: []) as! [String: Any]
    if let json = jsonRoot["json"] as? [String: Any],
        let val = json["value"] as? [String: Any],
        let attempt = val["failed_attempt"] as? String {
        print(attempt)
    }
} catch {
    print("Invalid data", error)
}
```

Comment: I have tried with _Any_ as well but do not give any results back. I will try to learn about codable for future.

Comment: Wait, how are you serializing the response? is `responseBody` a JSON object or is it the raw data you got back from the server.

Comment: Hmm looks like its a raw data provided by the server :(

Comment: @sjgmamer check my answer again, you'll need to use `JSONSerialization` to convert the data into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `Codable`, that's why, according to your JSON string I create `Codable` structures.

The JSONString should be:

```
let jsonString = """
{ "meta": { "expiration":0, "flags":33456 },
  "json": { "key":"String",
           "value":{ "failed_attempt":"3" },
         },
 "xattrs":{ "someAttribute":"someValue"}
}
"""
```

And the structures:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var meta: MetaData
    var json: JSONResponse
    var xattrs: Xattrs?
}

struct MetaData: Codable {
    var expiration: Int
    var flags: Int
}

struct JSONResponse: Codable {
    var key: String
    var value: JSONValue
}

struct JSONValue: Codable {
    var failed_attempt: String
}

struct Xattrs: Codable {
    var someAttribute: String
}

if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
{
    let myStruct = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
    print(myStruct?.json.value.failed_attempt)
}
```